# Magento 2: how to add a custom block in cart summary just after subtotal

Tags: magento2

how to add a custom block in cart summary just after subtotal in Magento 2 ?

I have followed many links, but none helped me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create this file in your custom module/theme to add custom Block on cart page.

**app/code/Mage/Mohit/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.totals.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.custom.block" before="checkout.cart.totals" template="Mage_Mohit::custom-block.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You need to create one template file here in your module or your theme.

**app/code/Mage/Mohit/view/frontend/templates/custom-block.phtml**

```
<?php echo "Custom Block"; ?>
```

And you make to custom module so create more two file like :-

**app/code/Mage/Mohit/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mage_Mohit',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Mage/Mohit/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mage_Mohit" setup_version="1.2.9"/>
</config>
```

And see output:-

[image]

And custom block show after order total check xml code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.totals.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.custom.block" template="Mage_Mohit::custom-block.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

Comment: I would like it to be below subtotal not above, if possible between subtotal and order total

Comment: Custom Block show after order total and check my update answer. So helpful this answer so accept and upvote answer because useful to other community Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your answer but my problem is that I would like the custom block to be between subtotal and order total

Comment: @MohitPatel, did you get solution to move after sub total?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom template just below the "**Subtotal**" on the **Cart page summary**. Just need to follow this code -

**NOTE - Don't forget to add `sortOrder`**

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- Add Custom Template -->
                        <item name="custom_template_below_subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/custom_template_below_subtotal</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/checkout/summary/custom_template_below_subtotal</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <!-- Add Custom Template -->
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```